# Checking whether any of some large collection of attributes has changed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have to check a large number of attributes and do something if any of them have changed. However, right now there are way too many or statements. Is there a better way to do this?

```
def check_updates
  if self.post_code_changed? || self.preferred_gender_changed?
    # do something
  elsif self.occupation_changed? || self.date_of_birth_changed? 
        || self.religion_changed? || self.smoke_changed? 
        || self.drink_changed? || self.drugs_changed? 
        || self.diet_changed? || self.looking_for_changed? 
        || self.edu_status_changed? || self.edu_type_changed?
    # do something else
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this an [tag:active-record] class? Please provide some context, and show how these attributes and `…_changed?` methods are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In the following, I'm assuming this is a regular `ActiveRecord`-derived model class, you're dealing with.)

I'd do something like this for a 1st pass (note that I've elided some of the many attribute names in the array):

```
def bio_updated?
  [:occupation, :date_of_birth, :religion, ...].any? do |attribute|
    __send__(:"#{attribute}_changed?")
  end
end
```

after which you can just call `self.bio_updated?`.

A second pass would be add some more declarative way of handling this at the model class level. E.g. implement something that'd let you write:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # idea is to write something like
  #
  #   tracked_attributes [group name], [array of attributes]
  #
  # to define stuff
  tracked_attributes :bio, [:occupation, :date_of_birth, :religion, ...]
  tracked_attributes :something_else, [...]
end
```

Which would do some meta-programming magic to give you a `bio_updated?` method and a `something_else_updated?` method (like seen above) you can call. (you may want to stick to `*_changed?` instead of `*_updated?` to keep to the Rails convention, though you can also argue that it'd be more confusing, since you're dealing with groups of attributes not single ones. Your call.)

There's probably a gem somewhere that does something like this already.

A middle way would be to abstract the `any?` matching into a generic method, just to stay DRY:

```
def bio_updated?
  any_attributes_changed? :occupation, :date_of_birth, :religion, ...
end

def something_else_updated?
  any_attributes_changed? ...
end

private

def any_attributes_changed?(*attrs)
  attrs.any? do |attribute|
    __send__(:"#{attribute}_changed?")
  end
end
```